# How do I set up a second remote database for integration testing?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, integration-testing, urlconnection

I need advice on what method will suit better for my case.

I have a Java application with Spring Boot, and right now, for the testing part, I use a localhost PostgreSQL database. The setup is quite simple; I just have the datasource.url/username/password and port setup in the application.properties file.

Now, I need to use a remote PostgreSQL database for a particular integration test class. So, as far as I know, I can do this in at least two ways:

- I can set up in application.properties another configuration for the remote database, and use it in the test class with `environment.getProperty()`.
- Or, I can make a bean to use those properties:

  ```
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
      DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
          dataSourceBuilder.url(dbUrl);
          dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
          dataSourceBuilder.password(password);
          return dataSourceBuilder.build();   
  }
  ```

And the things are not as simple as they may seem.
I have a class for tests configuration, **ClassA**.

I have a second class with actual tests, let's call it **ClassB**.

ClassB extends Class A, and ClassA starts a JAR file, which is another Java application which exposes some rest APIs, which will be tested with the tests from ClassB.

Now I use a local database, but I will want to use the remote one, in the future.

I managed to download the JAR file from Artifactory with a Maven dependency, and in the configuration class I search for the JAR file, I get the directory of it, and use an array of commands to run it: `{"java", "-jar", "directory.getCanonicalPath()}`, and `ProcessStreamer` to process it.

After I check the JAR file is up and running, the tests from ClassB are triggered, and they do CRUD operations against the recently opened application making REST calls to the APIs.

Any suggestions on how I can set up the second remote database?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems a bit complex and I'm not sure how to solve your exact problem. But I can suggest you look into using Docker for this type of integration testing; to both launch your other Rest API application and your secondary PostgresDB. You can use the Docker Java Client by [Spotify](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) to launch and tear down your dependent components from your test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saying you want to use both databases at once, I would create a separate data source for the remote database:

```
@Configuration
public class MultipleDBConfig {
    @Bean(name = "dbRemote")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.dbRemote")
    public DataSource dbRemoteDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbRemoteJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dbRemote") DataSource dbRemote) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(db1);
    }       
}
```

And then use them in your DAO/services:

```
@Autowired 
@Qualifier("dbRemoteJdbcTemplate") 
private JdbcTemplate dbRemoteTemplate;
```

If you can't use JdbcTemplates directly for that test case then I would suggest using RoutingDataSource from Spring.